# MySQL order by on varchar

Tags: mysql

In my table, there is a column called time.

Field type is varchar, value is like HH:MM , 02-25 ,21-42, 07-15

How to do the ordering by desc?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Generally, if you want to sort a table by some string, and you're not sorting alphanumerically or lexicographically, the values of interest should be stored in separate fields.

Comment: Is it possible , i have two field Date, Time , 
in one query i want to set two order by clause ,

in that one field as desc and another as ASC ,

example ORDER BY Date,Time DESC this is genral query , is it possible somthing like ORDER BY Date ASC,Time DESC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table_name order by column_name DESC;
```

where,

```
table_name is name of table and 
column_name is name of column in the table (independent of whatever the data-type)
```

Note:-`for proper o/p Your datatype for the time column should be datetime`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by:

```
ORDER BY CreationDate ASC,CreationTime DESC
```